# ArrayList to space splitted array to count number of words

Tags: java, arraylist, split

I need to count number of words in an arrayList object. I tried to use split but split give an error. My code is

```
public int countAdvertisementWords(ArrayList<String> adverts){

if(!(adverts.equals("")||adverts.equals(" ")||adverts==null))
    {
     String[] str;
     str = this.adverts.split("\\s+");
     numberOfWords = str.size();
     return numberOfWords;
    }
    else 
    return "";
}
```

How can I fix this problem or how can I write a code that counts number of word in an adverts set by

```
public void setAdverts(ArrayList<String> adverts) 
    {
    this.adverts = adverts;
    }
```

Comment: should we guess the error? as a sidenote, i´d start your if condition with `adverts==null`, otherwise you´d be running into a `NPE`

Comment: Lack of information. Could you show us some test cases?

Comment: I don't understand your code. 1. You want word count from all ArrayList Items or only from a String. 2. Your code intent to read a string only but you are reading a object. what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Fix the numerous compile errors in your code and then, if you are still having errors, post the runtime error here.

Comment: Thank you all I have a problem with situation and interpret to java, now ı solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over the length of the array list.Try something like this.

```
public int countAdvertisementWords(ArrayList<String> adverts){
int adverts_count=0;
for (int i = 0; i < adverts.size(); i++) {
    if(!adverts.get(i).equals(null)||!adverts.get(i).equals("")||!adverts.get(i).equals(" ")){
        adverts_count++;
    }else{
        //do nothing 
    }
}
    return adverts_count;
}
```

Hope this helps.Cheers.